# VS Code - Changed to .csproj, can't debug anymore

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I recently changed my project.json file to a .csproj file.

I tried launching a debugging instance but it returned the error:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: /Users/my_user/sf-build-ms-port/sfbuild-DotNetCore/project.json
```

And an error message:

```
The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1.
```

appeared at the top.

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <AssemblyName>sfbuild</AssemblyName>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <PackageId>sfbuild-DotNetCore</PackageId>
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" Version="4.3.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Process" Version="4.3.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And my debugging settings are:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/sfbuild.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
    }
]
}
```

I know the program is definitely the right path.

Comment: I have the same problem. After installing dotnet core on a new macbook I was unable to build without migrating to the "new" csproj file. Now VSCode is only a text editor - I can't start the debugger or attach the debugger after starting from the command line. I have made sure that I'm running the latest vscode and c# extension updates but still not working.